# Matplotlib dateformatter is not formatting the date as wished

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pycharm, dateformatter

I have this pandas dataframe and I would like to plot it by only showing the day, hour, min and secs.

[image]

As time, I have a Unix TimeStamp in ms and I convert it to the format you already see in the dataframe.

```
frm = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['startTime'] = pd.to_datetime((df['startTime']), unit='ms')
print(df)

plt.plot_date(df['startTime'], df['parameter.value'], linestyle='solid')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(frm)

plt.show()
```

Although I format it with the DateFormatter, still the mins and the secs do not appear in the plot.

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? This is just so that anyone answering can reproduce the problem and be able to diagnose it more effectively. It would be good to have an example including how your data frame is created and formatted.

Answer (score 1):

If the X axis is a string, the date/time format can be displayed without rounding.

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df['startTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startTime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print(df)

plt.plot_date(df['startTime'].astype(str), df['parameter.value'], xdate=True, linestyle='solid')
# plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
# plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(frm)

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a work-around, which in fact I knew. I am surprised why the DateFormatter does not work for %M:%S. However, thank you so much for your effort man. I marked the answer up, but I cannot accept it as the solution unfortunately.

Comment: `SecondLocator(interval=3000)` If you do this, it will be displayed in seconds, but the interval value will be in 3000 seconds, which doesn't meet your purpose, so you chose a string. I'm sorry it didn't meet your expectations.